# How can I change where Query results go in Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba

I have created a Query in Excel using the wizard and can successfully manipulate the query itself from VBA, but now I want to change where the results are displayed among multiple sheets.  Is there a "method" built in to manipulate this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to review the [FAQ] on the best way to ask questions to get good results. That said, post the code you are using and tell us what you would like it to do that it is not using and what you've tried so far. We can help much more effectively that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro of what you just did to create the query and then change the parameters you want in VBA. It should just be a matter of first selecting the cell where you want the results to land (prior to executing the query) "Range("A1").Select".

Once you have this code if you are still having problems changing the "target cells", edit this question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a query in Excel using the wizard, then it most-likely created a new connection in the workbook.  If so, go to the worksheet you want the data to appear on again, then go to the Data tab -> Get External Data group -> Existing Connections -> Double-click the connection -> choose your option for data delivery (Table, PivotTable, PivotTable and PivotChart).